# When I take pictures of text with my android the text is too blurry to read

Tags: camera, focus

I have tried this with two separate Android phones.

When I take a picture of text, say a letter posted on a window or a serial number on a device, etc., the text is out of focus and too blurry to read in the picture.

Often the text goes into focus in the camera for a split second but then immediately goes out of focus so that I am not able to take a picture of text where it is readable.

What is the solution to make text clear when I take pictures of it with my Android cam?

Comment: Have you tried to tell the camera app what area you want to focus? Usually this can be done by touching the area on the preview image.

Comment: Yes, that works thank you